# Printing the patterns using only one loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, design-patterns

I have printed this pattern using one loop:

```
*
**
***
****
*****

String s = "";
for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    s += "*";
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Now i want how to print following patterns using only one loop.

```
1)
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *

2)
  * * * * * 
   * * * *
    * * *
     * *
      *

3)
   1 2 3 4 5
   1 2 3 4
   1 2 3 
   1 2
   1
```

and other similar patterns using only **one loop**, I have done all of them using **more than one loop**.

Comment: So what do you think you would need to do?  How do you turn two loops into one?  e.g. what is the difference between loop 0..N-1 { loop 0..M-1 } and loop 0..N*M-1. They both go around the same number of times. ;)

Comment: Why is this specific requirement of single loop?

Comment: @RohitJain I am pretty sure these sort of questions are only as an acedemic exercise. ;)

Comment: I want optimization. The time complexity of two loops will be O(n^2) whereas for only one loop it will be O(n).  And O(n) < O(n^2).

Comment: Yes, printing triangle patterns can be very resources intensive in modern business information systems. It is understandable you need to reduce the complexity of it. This would give you a great deal of advantages before your competitors.

Comment: @coder005: If it's a matter of complexity, then you can use more than one loop, just not nested, and that would still be O(n). Number 3 is pretty easy with 2 loops (one after the other). (If we are strict, you'll never be able to print those things in O(n), since the print itself takes O(n²) )

Comment: @coder005 - I updated my solution to show you one way to make your triangle pattern #1, it could be easily updated to make any other pattern. Are stings functions OK for you to use, or are you counting those in the complexity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want optimization. The time complexity of two loops will be O(n^2) whereas for only one loop it will be O(n). And O(n) < O(n^2).

You realise that 99.999% of the time will be spent updating the console. If you want to save time, don't write anything.  The time taken to loop is trivial by comparison.

BTW The number of stars you produce will be O(N^2) so the time complexity with be O(N^2) whether you use 1, 2 or 3 loops.

Comment: can you explain briefly.I didn't got it.How can it be O(N^2) as there is only one for loop?

Comment: You need to produce N^2 stars, so the one loop has to iterate N^2 times. If you use three loops, it would still be O(N^2) The O is not just a matter of counting the number of loops. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The following code will print Diamond shape using single loop. You can change the value of size variable accordingly.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class DiamondShapeUsingSingleLoop{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int size = 5;
        for(int rowNumber = -size +1 ; rowNumber < size ; rowNumber++){
            char row[] = new char[2*size - Math.abs(rowNumber) - 1];
            Arrays.fill(row,0,Math.abs(rowNumber),' ');
            Arrays.fill(row,Math.abs(rowNumber), row.length,'*');
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(row));
        }
    }
}
```

Output is following :

```
    *                                                                                                                                                           
   ***                                                                                                                                                          
  *****                                                                                                                                                         
 *******                                                                                                                                                        
*********                                                                                                                                                       
 *******                                                                                                                                                        
  *****                                                                                                                                                         
   ***                                                                                                                                                          
    *
```

Comment: //Using same logic diamond shape can be printed using recursion only.

import java.util.Arrays;

public class DiamondShapeWithoutUsingLoop  {

 public static void main(String args[]){
  int size = 5;
  printRow(-size+1, size);
 }

 static void printRow(int rowNumber, int size){
  if(rowNumber==size) return;
  char row[] = new char[2*size - Math.abs(rowNumber) -1];
  Arrays.fill(row,0,Math.abs(rowNumber),' ');
  Arrays.fill(row,Math.abs(rowNumber), row.length,'*');
  System.out.println(String.valueOf(row));
  printRow(rowNumber+1,size);
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

```
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *
```

Write some requirements - then the solution becomes clear:

- on iteration **0**, print **1** `"* "` sequence  at position **4**
- on iteration **1**, print **2** `"* "` sequences at position **3**
- on iteration **2**, print **3** `"* "` sequences at position **2**
- on iteration **3**, print **4** `"* "` sequences at position **1**
- on iteration **4**, print **5** `"* "` sequences at position **0**

Comment: but the no. of lines is to be taken input from user then?? it should be generalised.

Comment: You showed three patterns with five lines each. No requirement for `n` lines. (which, btw. is trivial: start with `int numLines=5;` and implement the loop, then change the value to something else and read from the console, once the algorithm gives expected results for all input (including negative values, 0 and incredibly big numbers))

Comment: getting to position 4, 3 , 2 etc. requires a separate loop doesn't it? Or is there a way to multiply spaces?

Answer (score 0):

int col=1;
       int space=4;

```
   for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
       for(int j=1;j<=space;j++){
           System.out.print(" ");

    }
       space--;

    for(int j=1;j<=col;j++){
    System.out.print("*");
        }
    System.out.println();
    col=col+2;
```

Comment: why does this solve the question? don't dump your code here, explain!

Answer (score 0):

You can print diamond,by using only one loop 
and if you want to print pyramid use half logic of this program

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class DiamandOneLoop {

    public static void main(String arg[]){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the row Diamond Size");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        String numSp="                                                                   ";
        String spaceAdd=numSp.substring(0,n-1);
        StringBuilder space=new StringBuilder(spaceAdd);
        StringBuilder star=new StringBuilder("* ");

        for(int i=1;i<=n*2-1;i++){
            if(i<n){
                System.out.print(space);
                space.delete(0,1);
                System.out.println(star);
                star.append("* ");
            }
            if(i==n){
                System.out.println(star);
            }
            if(i>n){
                space.append(' ');
                System.out.print(space);
                star.delete(0,2); 
                System.out.println(star);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Print pattern using single loop:

the code is written in objective-c any one can use this logic and write program in their respective language.

int k = 5;

```
for (int i = 1; i<= k; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
    if (i==k) {
        i=0;
        k--;
        NSLog(@"\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4

1 2 3

1 2

1

Answer (score 0):

Try this JavaScript code:

```
count=0, j=0, str="";
while(count < 5) {
    if(j < 4 - count) {
        str += " ";
        j++;
    } else if(j < 5) {
        str += "* ";
        j++;
    } else {
        str += "\n";
        count++;
        j = 0;
    }
}
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution in c

```html
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n=15;
    int x=1;
    int j=1;
    for(int i=1;x<=n; )
    {

        if(!(j<=i))
        {
            cout<<endl;
            j=1;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"*";
            x++;
            j++;
        }

    }
}
```

Please feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

In JDK 11 onwards, we can print any basic pattern using single loop even with single statement. In JDK 11 we have a `String` method called `repeat`.

```
class Sample
{
 public static void main(String...arg)
 {
  int n = 5;
  
  System.out.println("\nPattern #1");
  for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
   System.out.println(" ".repeat(n-i)+"* ".repeat(i));
 }
}
```

Comment: String range method is also a loop  :P

Comment: Didn't understand your point, can you explain it.

Comment: The question was to solve the pattern problem in O(n) I mean in less complexity
but range is a loop in it self, so at the end we are using more loop then one

Answer (score -1):

> I want optimization. The time complexity of two loops will be O(n^2) whereas for only one loop it will be O(n). And O(n) < O(n^2).

Would the optimal solution be no loops?

```
System.out.println("     *\n    * *\n   * * *\n  * * * *\n* * * * *");
```

If you really want to do this with one loop, you can use the power of the comma operator and the String `format()` and `replace()` methods:

```
int j = triangle_levels - 1; // triangle_levels is some int you can make 5, but this 
                             // is more generic
for(int i = 0; i < triangle_levels; j--, i++) {
    System.out.println("%" + j + "s", " ");
    System.out.println("%0" + (i+1) + "d", 0).replace("0", "* "));
}
```

This will allow you to print the number of spaces without a second loop, followed by a pattern of `*`'s.

You can use this type of solution to make a triangle of any orientation.

Answer (score -1):

to make star pyramid with single loop

```
for(i=0; i<a; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<a-i-1; j++)
        printf(" ");
    for(j=0; j<2*i+1; j++)
        printf("*");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: This is three loops.